How do I fix this Javascript code on Chromebook?
I'm trying to fix a bug on https://github.com/betweenTheBrackets/windows-3.1-flying-windows-screensaver
When I download it and run it, the Windows logos aren't rendering instead just being rendered as coloured rectangles. This is on ChromeOS by the way.
Here is the app.js code:
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const fov = 75;
const aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
const near = 0.1;
const far = 1000;
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const flyingWindows = createFlyingWindows(40);
flyingWindows.forEach(flyingWindow => scene.add(flyingWindow));

camera.position.z = 2;

animate();
window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  camera.position.z -= 0.7;

  flyingWindows.forEach(flyingWindow => {
    if (camera.position.z < flyingWindow.position.z) {
      randomlyPositionFlyingWindow(flyingWindow, camera);
    }
  });

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function createFlyingWindows(qty) {
  // width and height are based on the aspect of the Windows logo image
  const width = 1.235;
  const height = 1;
  // arbitrary depth to make it appear flat enough
  const depth = 0.01;

  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(width, height, depth);
  const flyingWindows = [];

  const windowImageMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: loader.load('window-filter.png'),
    transparent: true,
    side: THREE.FrontSide,
  });

  const blackMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x000000,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    polygonOffset: true,
    polygonOffsetFactor: -1,
    polygonOffsetUnits: 1,
  });

  for (let i = 0; i < qty; i++) {
    const color = getRandomColor();

    // put color on both sides so transparent front can show color from inside box
    const colorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color,
      side: THREE.BackSide,
    });

    const materials = [
      blackMaterial,
      blackMaterial,
      blackMaterial,
      blackMaterial,
      windowImageMaterial, // side facing camera
      colorMaterial,       // back inside facing camera
    ];

    const flyingWindow = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials);
    randomlyPositionFlyingWindow(flyingWindow, camera);

    flyingWindows.push(flyingWindow);
  }

  return flyingWindows;
}

function randomlyPositionFlyingWindow(flyingWindow, camera) {
  // use the camera's z position to determine where to place them on the z axis
  flyingWindow.position.z = camera.position.z - Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) - 100;
  const distance = Math.abs(camera.position.z - flyingWindow.position.z);

  // based on how far away the flyingWindow is, push its X and Y position
  // add a little bit at the end to keep it away from the center slightly
  flyingWindow.position.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (distance / 3)) + 0.5;
  flyingWindow.position.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (distance / 3)) + 0.5;

  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    flyingWindow.position.x *= -1;
  }

  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    flyingWindow.position.y *= -1;
  }

  // reset the color with each reset (and leave the face with the Windows logo alone)
  const color = getRandomColor();
  flyingWindow.material[0].color.setHex = color;
  flyingWindow.material[1].color.setHex = color;
  flyingWindow.material[2].color.setHex = color;
  flyingWindow.material[3].color.setHex = color;
  flyingWindow.material[5].color.setHex = color;
}

function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

I don't know what's causing the problem in the first place so if anyone knows please tell me.
I tried to change the window-filter.png file (which by the way all of the files are in the same folder) to the file:///home/chronos/ etc. etc.
Didn't work.
Used AI error fixers on all the files.
Didn't work.
Again, please tell me what's causing the problem and send me the fixed code if you can.

Hi, how you running it? You need to run it using some server. because browser will block acces to local files, if you just open index.html file. Try vs code live server extension, it should help with loading png file. I think you will have error in console, about this file openning.
